# when calling a method in node js the value returned is [object Promise] were as the console output is printing the value

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am a newbie to nodejs and promises, i am trying to fetch some data from json and pass them to other function for further processing, here is my code.

```
const test = tests.fetchAll().then(test1 => {
    const testsDataArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(test1))
    const testsData = testsDataArray.data
    const testsId = testsData.find(iid => iid.ips === '1.2.3.4')
    // console.log(testsId.id)
    console.log(testsId)
    return testsId.id.toString()
  })
```

this has a json which is used in the above code

```
{
  id: 36,
  name: 'p ',
  seats: 10,
  description: 'Test description',
  contact: 'p@xyz.com',
  created_at: '2019-12-31T11:18:19.000Z',
  updated_at: null,
  ips: '1.2.3.4',
  domains: 'xyz.com',
  termination_date: null,
  seats_used: null
}
```

when I run the following code :

```
test.then(result => {
    console.log(result)
  })
```

the output printed on console is '36', where as when i return the same, it returns [object Promise]

```
test.then(result => {
        console.log(result)
      })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `test` is a promise.  The ONLY way to get the value from it is is inside a `.then()` handler or by using `await` on the promise.

If you add `return result` to your `.then()` handler, that just keeps `result` as the resolved value of the next promise.  It doesn't magically make `result` a regular, non-asynchronous return value.

Please remember that `promise.then()` returns ANOTHER promise.  So, returning a value from a `.then()` handler just makes it the resolved value of this additional promise that is returned.

So, if you did this:

```
const p = test.then(result => {
    return result;
});
console.log(p);          // this is still just a promise
```

All, you've done is made a new promise with `test.then()` and made `result` the value of that new promise.  You STILL have to use `.then()` or `await` on `p` to get the value from it.  You always have to get a value out of a promise with `.then()` or `await` no matter how many times you return it from a `.then()` handler or from an `async` function.